# numpy.searchsorted with 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, search, numpy

I have this numpy array where the values in each row will always be sorted and monotonically increasing:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 8],
       [2, 5, 6, 7, 8],
       [5, 7, 11, 12, 13]])
```

and I want to search for the following values (which are NOT sorted or monotonic) for each row:

```
b = np.array([4.5, 2.3, 11.6])
```

so that I get an answer of:

```
[4, 1, 3]
```

However, searchsorted does not support this (it feels like it needs an `axis` keyword).

Is there an EFFICIENT way I can do this for a very large array? Obviously with a `for` loop I can index the array `a` and `b` like this:

```
for i in np.arange(np.alen(a)):
     print a[i].searchsorted(b[i])
```

but this is slow when `a` is large.

Is there a way to do this in numpy that is more efficient?

Comment: why the negative score on this question?

Answer (score 2):

You can searchsorted on the ravel/flattened array:

```
In [11]: np.searchsorted(a.ravel(), b)
Out[11]: array([3, 6])
```

You can then use divmod on the result (which gets the row and column):

```
In [12]: divmod(np.searchsorted(a.ravel(), b), a.shape[1])
Out[12]: (array([0, 1]), array([3, 1]))
```

Comment: That requires that every row has larger values then any preceding row, which is the case of the OP's example, but seems a strong condition for general arrays.

Comment: @Andy - an elegant solution to the example in the question, but, as Jamie says, it does not work for cases where b is not monotonically ascending. I have updated the question so it is more clear. Thanks.

Comment: @KernowBunney ah, ok so something more efficient but similar to `np.diag(np.apply_along_axis(np.searchsorted, 1, a, b))`. Dropping to cython is an easy option for perf of your for loop.

Comment: @Andy Hayden - thanks for that - apply_along_axis works and is at least more succinct/Numpy-like than a Python loop. I will investigte Cython. Cheers!

Comment: @AndyHayden, apply_along_axis is great!

Comment: @GoingMyWay. `apply_along_axis` is a glorified python level `for` loop under the hood, just like `vectorize`